# Cannot get separate views to appear in index.html, and controller is also not working

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-routing

I'm just starting out with Angular and most of programming in general. I'm trying to make a separate view1.html file appear on my index.html page but it won't, so I'm assuming it's a routing problem. I tried pasting the view1.html content in the body of my index.html to test it and it wasn't showing the controller content either. I'm sure they're simple mistakes but I can't find them. view.html is in a separate folder called views. I only have the javascript in the index.html page for convenience.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='demoApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>


<script>
// create module called "demoApp" under the variable name "demoApp"
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

// ROUTING
    demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when ('/',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'views/view1.html'
            })
        .when('/view2',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'views/view2.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });


// CONTROLLERS
demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
        { name: 'Caleb', city: 'Indianapolis' },
        { name: 'Samantha', city: 'Zionsville' },
        { name: 'Tim', city: 'Palo Alto' }
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
        $scope.customers.push(
            {
                name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city
            });
    };
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

view1.html

```html
<h2>View 1</h2>
Name:
<input type="text" ng-model="name" />

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="cust in customers"></li>
</ul>

Customer Name:
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
<br>Customer City:
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
<br>

<button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>

<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the script for angular's router.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Also, looks like you're missing a closing `</head>` tag.

Here's a working version of your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='demoApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>


<script>
// create module called "demoApp" under the variable name "demoApp"
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

// ROUTING
    demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when ('/',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'view1.html'
            })
        .when('/view2',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'view2.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });


// CONTROLLERS
demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
        { name: 'Caleb', city: 'Indianapolis' },
        { name: 'Samantha', city: 'Zionsville' },
        { name: 'Tim', city: 'Palo Alto' }
    ];

    $scope.newCustomer = { name: "", city: ""};

    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
        $scope.customers.push(
            {
                name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city
            });
    };
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just added both of those and nothing changed.

Comment: You'll also need to add 'ngRoute' to your dependencies:  var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);    And you're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your demoApp.controller, after the last } should be });   I made these changes and posted the working code I have in the answer.